# Best way to wait for the deletion of a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++

I have a scenario where the objects created as `shared_ptr`s are resources and some steps have to wait until those resources have been fully released.

`shared_ptr` has the member function `use_count()`, but relying on that would mean a loop check which is not very efficient.

Would it be a good idea to wrap the `shared_ptr` in another class that constructs it with a custom deleter that sets an event flag that the users of this wrapper can wait on (using `condition_variable`)?

Alternatively, does it make sense to create my own shared_ptr that simply adds such `wait_for_released()` functionality?

Comment: custom deleter sounds reasonable, but there is a possibility that two or more things have been needlessly conflated, jumbled up, and that some redesign will let you simply declare the relevant resources as local variables, automatically destroying themselves at correct time

Comment: @NFRCR Can you mention what you finally went with? I'm looking for solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might get by with a mutex locked by the resource-owning objects - they can release the mutex from their destructor.  The waiter waits on the mutex rather than anything directly related to the shared pointer.